# Eclipse + Pydev not breaking on external library source breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, pydev

I've got a project (A) which references code in a different project (B). I've linked the two by adding B into the External Libraries list in A. So PyDev PYTHONPATH now has Source Folders as project A's source, and External Libraries contains B's source path.

The problem I'm having is that breakpoints set in B are ignored, and the code does not break at these points. To clarify, the Breakpoints list shows these breakpoints, and I'm able to double click on them and go to the target file. The breakpoint is enabled (green dot with a checkmark) and there's nothing different from these external breakpoints and breakpoints in the main project.

I've tried everything except completely re-installing Eclipse:

- Delete projects and re-import
- Remove and re-import the external library project
- Clear all breakpoints and re-try
- Compare my configuration against another machine

This very same configuration (as far as i can tell) works on another developer's machine without any problems. So it appears that there's a configuration I'm missing, or something in Eclipse is corrupt that I need to reset. So any suggestion about resetting Eclipse to the appropriate settings would be helpful.

Sysinfo: OSX 10.6.4, Eclipse 3.6.1, PyDev 1.6.2.2010090812, Python 2.5

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

You cannot set a break-point until the external library has actually been loaded, so you need to first set a breakpoint in the main source at a point where it has called into the library. Now at this point you can set or enable the breakpoints in the library code itself.

Comment: This may be the case but it's not consistent. On some machines I'm able to set breakpoint in the library with no problem. And on mine even when i set a breakpoint in my source after library load, then set a breakpoint in the library, that breakpoint is still not triggered.

Comment: Are those machines using the same operating system and running under the same environment?

Comment: After battling with this issue for months I've finally found the only solution was to install Aptana :) Reinstalling eclipse did not help. AptanaStudio 3 works great. Wish I could have figured out what was happening so that I could post a solution, but unfortunately this is just a work-around (which at least gets things working again).

Answer (score 0):

I think i have run into the same problem: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486871/pydev-breakpoints-not-working][1]

No solution yet. I could actuallu step into the methods where the breakpoints weren't working, set a breakpoint some lines below and still it would be ignored. Aptana did't solve the problem for me.