# Pycharm debugger does not stop on breakpoints

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, pycharm

I have a flask project I am trying to debug (this was working absolutely ok till few hours ago) - When I debug the project, I see the following :

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 135.1057)
/Users/vantani/cp/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --save-  
signatures --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49223 --file /Users/vantani/cp/unnamed/manage.py server
pydev debugger: process 484 is connecting

/Users/vantani/cp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py:152: UserWarning: Flask-  
Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
warnings.warn("Flask-Cache: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, "
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
pydev debugger: process 498 is connecting
```

As I said this setup was working fine. Now,  the debugger does not stop at the breakpoint and the debugger window is empty. I see that there are two processes created by PyDev and I guess that is causing this issue. I have restarted my machine and there is only one pycharm process running.

Comment: While your program is running in debug mode, what happens if you press `Pause Program` on the left ? If it works you should be able to see the frame your program was in when you pressed that button.

Comment: Same issue here with PyCharm remote debugging. Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 33):

Sometimes this might be caused by the fact that some other module is using the same tracing api (`sys.settrace`) as debugger, for instance `Coverage.py`. The solution would be to go to your *Rub/Debug Configurations* and add `--no-cov` flag to the *Additional Arguments*.

Alternatively you might want to delete all `--cov` in pytest settings (i.e. `pytest.ini`) or run tests with `--no-cov` flag, i.e.

```
    pytest test.py --no-cov
```

It might be also caused by a bad filename, e.g. your file/directory has special characters or spaces in it. Try removing them or changing to e.g. underscore (`_`).

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped!

Comment: Exactly! Debug doesn't work if coverage is enabled.

Comment: How do you "go to your Rub/Debug Configurations and add --no-cov flag to the Additional Arguments"? Is this some box in preferences or something I type into the terminal?

Comment: @ShepBryan Note the question is about PyCharm not stopping on breakpoints. This setting is available in PyCharm [here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2021.1/py_runConfigMenu.png). If you're not using PyCharm then you'll need to run tests with `--no-cov` flag added to `pytest` (see my answer). For VSCode, add `"env": {"PYTEST_ADDOPTS": "--no-cov"}` to a relevant `launch.json` configuration.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for so long, thanks !

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the --no-cov flag

Answer (score 26):

There is an issue with the debugger in PyCharm lately.
I'm on mac using PyCharm 2020.2 and while the debugger would stop at tests, it wouldn't stop when running the dev server for django.

For me disabling `Gevent compatible` option in `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment` has helped.
[image]

Worth noting that some suggest to enable some suggest to disable that option - so it's worth having a go at each and see if that helps your case.

Comment: PyCharm 2020.3.3 (Professional Edition). Unchecking `Gevent compatible` helped

Comment: This worked for me too, what is the use of gevent compatible option?

Comment: It worked for me as well

Comment: Why is this happening? I switched this on so that I can use debugger inside gevent threads which was working for sometime. But then this issue started happening.

Answer (score 11):

Just need set flask's debug mode off, such as

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was not obvious to me.

Comment: Where do you copy this line of code to? Do I put it at the top of the file I am trying to run?

Comment: This was the problem for me

Answer (score 4):

Check your python debugger settings, and clear your cache, This helped me

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have a flask project but I had the same problem. In my case I had to change the project-path! There were umlauts (ü,ä,ö) in it. By removing them the breakpoints worked again.

Answer (score 3):

My problem is solved when I installed pydevd-pycharm

```
pip install pydevd-pycharm
```

Also here is a useful link for this problem.
[github from jetbrains intellij-community](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/python/helpers/pydev)

Answer (score 2):

The following workaround should help. I had a same problem in a simple Python script. PyCharm debugger didn't stop on a simple breakpoint and just ran to the end.

Thanks to Gabriel's answer, I checked the path to my script and it had Russian letters. Because I use Russian Windows and it creates admin user named 'Administrator' using Russian letters.

I changed the Russian letters to use only English letters from the project-path (just copied PyCharm projects folder to the root of disk and reloaded my project from new place. Nothing else was changed!). And the debugger immediately started working just fine and stopped on breakpoints!

It looks like this a bug that PyCharm debuger can't work with different national letters in the path. It very common situation outside English-speaking countries.

Answer (score 2):

For Sanic case.
Run `go_fast(..auto_reload=False,..)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a long thread about this issue on JetBrains forums:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008107400-PyCharm-2020-1-not-stopping-on-breakpoints-anymore-. Reading through that thread is like reading a black magic book, everyone has their own voodoo $^$#

I ran into this issue with 2021.1.1 CE and a brand new project. My solution was to **change the default test runner to pytest**. YMMV. If that thread is any indication, debugging might stop working if it rains tomorrow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me I deleted project from "recent projects in pycharm" then I opened project direct from repository. It works again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue recently (July 2021 PyCharms 2021.1.3 CE) for days trying everything I could find online would not work.  Then found under File --> Manage IDE Settings --> Restore Default Setting, that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by removing coverage config from pytest.ini

Comment: I had a tox.ini file and after removing the coverage, breakpoint is working now. But I need coverage report. Is there any way to use one tox.ini for debugging and another for CI?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, PyCharm breakpoints worked yesterday on a particular program and did not work today on the same program (with no other apparent changes).

Another thread suggested setting PyCharm's debug option, through an environmental variable to log information about what PyCharm saw when executing my program: `PYCHARM_DEBUG=True`. With this option set, PyCharm logged that it recognized my breakpoints, but PyCharm blew through the breakpoints nonetheless.

I found the solution was to install a new Python interpreter and point PyCharm to that interpreter.

I found that the debugger worked properly with the new interpreter.

Although this is not a satisfying solution, I'll take what I can get after several hours of frustration.

Comment: Thanks @ahinkle for posting. This helped me a lot. Really really frustrating problem. I installed the latest Python interpreter. and breakpoints started working again.

Answer (score 0):

For all those people that have the same problem, but can't resolve it, maybe this will work:

The problem could be, that pydev isn't connecting to its subprocess.
Check if the option "**Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging?**" in the **debugger settings** is set. You can find it in File > Settings >  Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger (current version of PyCharm)

Usually there is also a short hint in the console but I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

After removing `debug_toolbar` middleware the debugger is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of a third party module. I tried all the solutions listed and none worked for me.
I changed the interpreter that I'm using and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running remote interpreter from docker-compose. It disappeared when I set `Working directory` to my project root directory in Run/Debug Configuration. I also restarted Pycharm and invalidated caches.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same case but, if you are using the Debug Server to debug a docker container, the only thing which made the breakpoint to stop for me is to set and environment variable for the container:

```
PYCHARM_DEBUG=True
```

PyCharm Version: 2022.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. At some point in my code breakpoints did not stop anymore.

I found this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486871/pydev-breakpoints-not-working" extremely helpful to solve this issue.

I ran into a recursion and somehow the exception was eaten away.

Answer (score -1):

For me PyCharm actually executed a different file. If you just clicked the run button... try if it makes a difference if you use 
right click on file => Run 'xy'.

Or double check if your file full path to be executed is specified in "Script path" in the run configuration. I used to use the file name in "interpreter option" along with "working directory" specified. It would work that way.