# pycharm debugging conflicts with coverage package in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

Running Pycharm debugger raise following exception:

```
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
PYDEV DEBUGGER WARNING:
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.
This may cause the debugger to stop working correctly.
If this is needed, please check: 
http://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html
to see how to restore the debug tracing back correctly.
Call Location:
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coverage/collector.py", line 278, in _installation_trace
    sys.settrace(None)
```

> As the exception shows, there is a conflict between Pycharm debugger and [**coverage**](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) package.

Here are my Pycharm execution configurations:

[image: Pycharm execution configuration 1]
[image: Pycharm execution configuration 2]

**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might encounter this error, I'll share my solution.

I initialized the [**coverage**](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) **package** in a module and import the module somewhere in my code by mistake.
therefore the [**coverage**](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/) package was initialized and set system trace to **None** and prevents Pycharm debugger from running.

### Other cases

I was running the flask server but for those who encounter this exception in running tests, see [Pycharm debugger does not stop on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400621/pycharm-debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints)