# PyDev ignoring breakpoints

Tags: python, pydev, web2py

I have been using PyDev with Eclipse successfully for a couple of years. Recently it has started ignoring breakpoints...not quite all the time, they do work occasionally, but most of time (even on the same code).
I searched and saw this post which was very useful:
[pydev breakpoints not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486871/pydev-breakpoints-not-working)

I too have sys.gettrace() returning None
Python 2.7.8 on Windows 8.1

I put the trace_func at the start of my code and it ends up with the below.
rocket.py function is here:
https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/rocket.py#L166

Am not sure what to do next to try & solve the issue.
Many thanks for any assistance :)

```
Context:  isEnabledFor  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py   Line: 1359  Event: return
Context:  info  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py   Line: 1159  Event: return
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 166   Event: call
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 167   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 168   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 169   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 176   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 192   Event: call
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 195   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 196   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 198   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: line
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\socket.py     Line: 197   Event: return
Context:  close     File: C:\Bin\web2py\gluon\rocket.py     Line: 176   Event: return
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 150   Event: call
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 161   Event: line
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 162   Event: line
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 163   Event: line
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 166   Event: line
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 167   Event: line
Context:  _qsize    File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 200   Event: call
Context:  _qsize    File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 201   Event: line
Context:  _qsize    File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 201   Event: return
Context:  get   File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\Queue.py  Line: 168   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 308   Event: call
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 331   Event: line
Context:  _is_owned     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 299   Event: call
Context:  _is_owned     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 302   Event: line
Context:  _is_owned     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 306   Event: line
Context:  _is_owned     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 306   Event: return
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 333   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 334   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 335   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 336   Event: line
Context:  _release_save     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 293   Event: call
Context:  _release_save     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 294   Event: line
Context:  _release_save     File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 294   Event: return
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 337   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 338   Event: line
Context:  wait  File: C:\Bin\Python27\lib\threading.py  Line: 339   Event: line
```

Comment: Have you recently updated your eclipse, python, pydev, or java installed versions?

Comment: All have been updated over time...eclipse/pydev both updated after the problem manifested to try & fix

Answer (score 0):

The common problem is that whenever Python enters into a situation where there's some recursion error it stops the debugger.

You can see the report at Python at: https://bugs.python.org/issue10933 (so, the usual trick is setting a tracing function which prints until the print which will stop printing, which means that's the place where the tracing was disabled automatically by Python).

As a workaround you can use programmatic breakpoints as you'd do with pdb (type 'pydevd' and request a code-completion and a template will appear with the proper way to make the pydevd.settrace()).

In this case you can either start in debug mode or you can use the remote debugger -- see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for details on how to use the remote debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem that break points are ignored.try this....
in squish window->show view->click on breakpoints->make the skip all breakpoints disable

if breakpoints are not visible in show view go to other->debug->breakpoints

This may work

Comment: This is suited to be a comment nor an independent answer!